# Употребление мягкого знака в прилагательных

Tags: грамматика

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: 1.   Почему в слове юрмальчанин – стоит мягкий знак перед окончанием? (Исходное слово Юрмала)
2.  Как должно писаться слово Межмальская (или Межмалская)? Исходное - Межмале (произносится конечное е как э)
Эти слова употребляются в Латвии.

Comment: Очень часто, когда образуется сочетание ЛЧ не только из мягкой, но и из твёрдой Л, Л смягчается и получается ЛЬЧ. Например, село — односельчанин, галка — гальчонок, белка — бельчонок, стрела — стрельчатый.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой благодарю! Но что означает "очень часто"? И уверены ли вы в слове гальчонок?

Comment: Ой, точно, "галчонок" без Ь! Простите! Всё равно часто. ;)

Comment: _Евгения Рузина: Как должно **писаться** слово Межмальская (или Межмалская)?_ === А как оно **произносится**?

Comment: Это трудноуловимо ) Впрочем, мне кажется все-таки, что с мягким знаком.

Answer (score 1):

***Юрмала — юрмальчанин, Межмале — межмальский.***

Мягкость или твердость звука Л всегда обозначается  по слуху, мягкий знак пишется, если Л произносится мягко.

Таким образом, выбор мягкого знака определяется по тому произношению, которое характерно для этих производных слов.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=25#pp25

Примечание 2. В большинстве прилагательных с суффиксом -ск- согласный л перед суффиксом — мягкий, поэтому после л пишется ь, напр.: сельский, уральский, барнаульский. Однако в некоторых прилагательных, образованных от нерусских собственных географических названий, сохраняется твердый л, и поэтому ь не пишется, напр.: кызылский, ямалский (наряду с вариантами кызыльский, ямальский).

Comment: Большое спасибо, Шарон! Теперь душенька успокоилась ))